# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working anymore when adding MasterPage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I call a javascript function from C# like this :

```
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "script", "$(function () {initializeMap(); });", true);
```

It worked perfectly until I add a master Page :

```
MasterPageFile="~/Header.master
```

`<%@ Register Assembly="myassembly" Namespace="mynamesapce" TagPrefix="mytag" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>`

And put my code in an asp Content :

`<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" runat="Server">`

After I added all of this the javascript function call wasn't working anymore, and I got this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

and when I click on the error it gets me too

`$(function () {initializeMap(); });`

Do you have an idea of the problem ?

Comment: This "$ not defined" error, mostly comes up when jQuery lib is not loaded.

Comment: That's what I was thinking first but all the other scripts I include (bootstrap for example) are working well..

Comment: or referenced multiple times, check for duplicate reference in master as well in child page

Comment: Have a look at your rendered HTML. See where your `$(function(){})` is positioned and where the jQuery lib is being loaded.

Comment: I added an other MasterPage and it seems to work now... On the first masterPage there wasn't any scripts includes so don't really know what happend

Comment: I had the same problem ,I used the ScriptManager in the MasterPage and removed it from the rest of the pages works fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

I bet that your jQuery declaration, if it is still being declared, is in a different position in the HTML.

I tend to use `RegisterStartupScript`, though not bulletproof, but is less likely to cause these issues because the script will be rendered at the bottom of the page.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "script", "$(function () {initializeMap(); });", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="400"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                    <!-- end of secondary bar -->

 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

add the `ScriptManager` only in `MasterPage` and remove it From every other Pages and then give it a try..